# Delphi function and equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, delphi

Old library was written in Delphi. Now I'm trying to write library in c++.

Below there is function in Delphi's library:

`function MyFunction(Path:string; Options:PInteger; var Data: array of Byte):Integer; stdcall;`

How should this function look in C++? Is below declariation right?

`int __stdcall MyFunction(char* Path, int* Options, char* Data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem is the buffer. Your Delphi function passes an open array. This is implemented by passing both the array length, and the pointer to the first element. Your C++ translation does not do that. You'll need to pass an extra parameter specifying the length of the array.

Since you can expect that the function will not modify `Path` you would likely declare the first parameter as `const char*`.

So, the function would then look like this:

```
int __stdcall MyFunction(const char* Path, int* Options, size_t len, char* Data);
```

Now, if you are expecting that the function is to be binary interchangeable with the original C++ version you have a problem. You'd need to match the internal implementation of a Delphi open array. You can do that. The function would become:

```
int __stdcall MyFunction(const char* Path, int* Options, char* Data, int high);
```

Note that the length parameter appears after the pointer to the first element, and is named high. That's because a Delphi open array receives `high(A)` rather than `Length(A)`.

You really must get out of the habit of passing Delphi specific types across interop boundaries.

Of course, I'm assuming here that you are still creating a library for interop and this function is at the interop boundary. If the function is internal then the declaration would perhaps be:

```
void MyFunction(const std::string &path, int &options, 
    const std::vector<char> &data);
```

There's no need for a return value since errors can be signalled with exceptions. Strings are stored in `std::string`, and a byte array in C++ is `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @JensG Not across an interop boundary. That would place a constraint that both libraries used the same dynamic runtime.

Comment: @JensG Well, the use of `__stdcall` and the mention of library makes it seem likely that my assumption is valid. You also are assuming context. You are assuming that this is not interop. And if it's not interop then the declaration is `void MyFunction(const std::string &path, int &options, const std::vector<char> &data)`

Comment: C++ Dll must interop with Delphi application. I have one more question, is `char name [255]` equivalent of `name: String[255]`?

Comment: No it is not. string[255] has length in byte 0 and payload in bytes 1..255. You really ought to stop doing interop with private Delphi types .....